# Prove that regular curves are locally invertible

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry

Consider the function $F = (F_1, F_2)$ from $I = (a, b) \subset \mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$  (without loss of generality, assume $n = 2$). Suppose $F$ is differentiable (i.e $F_1' = f_1$ and $F_2' = f_2$ exist) and $F'(t) \neq 0$ for all $t \in I$.

Let $t_0$ be fixed. Now,
by multiple applications of the single variable mean value theorem
$$ F(t) - F(t_0) = f^*(t) (t - t_0) \qquad(*)
$$
where
$$ (t - t_0)f^*(t) = (F_1(t) - F_1(t_0), F_2(t) - F_2(t_0)) = (t - t_0)(f_1(\xi_1), f_2(\xi_2))
$$
for $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$ between $t$ and $t_0$.

**Remarks**

1. $f^*(t)$ is not necessarily in $f(I)$, but
2. $\lim_{t \to t_0} f^*(t) = f(t_0).$
3. If $f^*(t) \neq 0$ in $(*)$ then $F$ is injective at $t_0$ (Suppose ($F(t) - F(t_0) = 0$. Then, since $f^*(t) \neq 0$, $t - t_0$ must be. Hence, if $F(t) = F(t_0)$ then $t = t_0$.)

In differential geometry parlance we say that $F$ is *regular* if $f(t) \neq 0$ for all $t \in I$. We want to show that all regular curves are locally invertible (in the sense of the inverse function theorem).

Suppose $F$ is regular. Using the limit in the remark, we can choose an $\epsilon$-neighborhood centered at $f(t_0) \neq 0$ to exclude $0$. Then $f^*(t)$ must be in this neighborhood, and hence be non-zero, which as we remarked, means that $F$ is locally injective at $t_0$.

**Questions**

1. Is the proof above correct?
2. Is the continuity of $f$ required? I know it's required in the more general version of the question, the inverse function theorem. But I don't think I used it

Thanks,
LMZ.

**References**

"Differential Geometry" (1989), by Stoker provides a similar proof to the one proof as outlined above. However, the proof is not very detailed and makes use of the continuity of f', which I don't think is necessary.

Comment: What is $f$? What is $f^*$? What does "for some $f^*$" mean? If you mean that there exists a function $f^*$ such that (*) holds, that has nothing to do with the MVT; (*) holds if and only if $f^*(t)=(F(t)-F(t_0))/(t-t_0)$.

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant since I have no idea what's going on here, but you should probably note that MVT is false for functions from $[a,b]$ to $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: $f$ is the derivative of $F$ and $f^* = (f_1(\xi_1), f_2(\xi_2))$ where $\xi_1, \xi_2$ are strictly between $t$ and $t_0$. How do we get $f_1$ (for example)? Note that $F_1(t) - F_1(t_0) = f(\xi_1)(t - t_0)$ for some $\xi_1$ by the MVT.

Comment: Was there some way we were supposed to know that $f=F'$ or that $f^*$ is what you say it is? Never mind. I have no idea why such an $f^*$ should exist. You don't need any of this to show what I suspect you want to show,

Comment: are you really meaning invertible like in inverse function theorem? In that theorem the dimension of the domain and codomain are the same. btw. please update question with details about $f$ and $f^*$.

Comment: @user251257 there is a more general version of the theorem from a subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. (I think it's possible to define the Jacobian of a non-square matrix by throwing some elements out)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I've updated the question with more detail

Comment: do you probably mean the constant rank theorem?

Comment: If the proof doesn't use continuity of the derivative then it's not correct; the result is not true for differentiable functions. Where the error is I couldn't say, but your remark (3) makes very little sense to me...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I'll update the question in that case with more detail

Comment: I should revise my comment - I don't see why (2) would be true if $f$ is not continuous. (And again, something in the proof _is_ wrong, since you're proving something false...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich That makes sense. Could you provide more detail on why continuity is required for (2), then? If you change your answer to that, or add it to your answer, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: I gave a counterexample in my answer. What more do you want?

Comment: sorry, I got stuck before I got to the counterexample (as I wrote in a comment to the answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *suspect* that all you want to prove is this: If $F:(a,b)\to\Bbb R^n$ is continuously(!) differentiable and $F'(t_0)\ne0$ then $F$ is injective in some neighborhood of $t_0$.

This is very easy. Some component of $F'(t_0)$ must be non-vanishing; wlog say $F_1'(t_0)>0$. Since $F'$ is continuous, $F_1'>0$ in some nieghborhood of $t_0$. Hence $F_1$ is strictly increasing and hence injective there, and hence $F$ is injective there.

Simple examples with $n=1$ show this is false if you assume just that $F$ is differentiable. For example, if $F:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ satisfies $F(0)=0$ and $F(t)=t+t^2\sin(1/t^{10})$ for $t\ne 0$ then $F$ is differentiable, $F'(0)=1$, but $F$ is not monotone in any neighborhood of the origin.

Comment: Do you mean $F'(t_0)$ must be non vanishing (as opposed to $F'(0)$). Also, I don't see how $F_1$ being injective means that $F$ is injective.

Comment: Yes, I meant $t_0$, thanks. Regarding your second comment, here's an exercise: If $a\ne b$ then $(a,c)\ne (b,d)$.